# Jquery: How to disable siblings dropdown value across <TR>

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table like this:

```
<table class="mytable">
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="go">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="go">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="go">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="go">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="go">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and my jquery code like this:

```
$(".go").change(function(){
    var selVal=[];
    $(".go").each(function(){
        selVal.push(this.value);
    });

    $(this).closest('tr').siblings(".go").find("option").removeAttr("disabled").filter(function(){
       var a=$(this).parent("select").val();
       return (($.inArray(this.value, selVal) > -1) && (this.value!=a))
    }).attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ev5qvprv/121/)

How do i disable siblings value if i select 1 on this dropdown, but i should not able to select the 1 on another dropdown again. Here is the working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ev5qvprv/2/) that work perfectly without table/td/. My requirement come across to use table tr/td. I tried to use: `$(this).closest('tr').siblings(".go")`
but its not working. any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing `tr` to `.siblings()`

```
$(this).closest("tr").siblings("tr").find("option")
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ev5qvprv/122/

Comment: Work greats.. thank you. Changed to  $(this).closest('tr').siblings("tr").find(".go option")

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by finding the closest table first .. and then find ".go" except the current one

Answer (score 0):

The selector you used is not correct.

```
$(this).closest('tr').siblings(".go").find("option")
```

This will give you nothing because `tr` doesn't have any sibling `.go`.

You have two solutions for the selector:

```
$(this).closest('tr').siblings("tr").find("option")
```

or

```
$('table.mytable').find("option")
```